# How to quickly straighten a tooth

Tags: personal-care

Is it possible to re-adjust a tooth so that it is straighter in a short space of time in a safe manner.

My right lateral incisor has been slightly twisted since I first got it, but it is a pain to clean. Would it be possible to straighten it safely within a week or so?

Comment: Any possible answers will probably be a bad idea...

Comment: I appreciate that, and will take any advice with a pinch of salt.

Comment: We're not doctors. We should **not** be answering this question, and it should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for medical advice. We've deemed those types of questions to be off-topic, mainly due to the strong possibility of causing more harm than good.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this discussion because [the policy is that medical question are not inherently off-topic](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-medical-is-too-medical) and this one does not seem problematic. Cc @Wipqozn

Comment: @Sterno On the contrary, [we've deemed those questions to be on-topic by default](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-medical-is-too-medical).

Comment: @Gilles: This question should be closed because it *is* dangerous for us to answer it, because we're not doctors, and thus we're not able to know if any methods given for straightening a tooth won't cause any damage to their gums, teeth, et cetera. We should always ere on the side of caution when dealing with the on-topicness of medical advice questions.

Comment: @Wipqozn If you disagree with the policy, please participate in the [meta thread](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-medical-is-too-medical). Individual questions are not the place to go against a consensual policy (+20 answer in favor, opposing answer scoring -1).

Comment: @Gilles The meta doesn't support your position at all, and I'm not sure how you drew the conclusion that all medical questions are on-topic from it. Shogs post says it was too early to paint a "ban all medical advice" questions, and that we should judge questions on a case by case basis. As our number of medical advice questions grow, then we could form a more structured policy. In this specific case, I'm saying it is *dangerous* for us to answer this question, and it falls outside our expertise and therefore our scope.

Comment: You're halfway right, @Gilles. I agree that I was wrong and they are not categorically deemed off-topic. But the meta you linked doesn't really say "They're great! Allow them!" either. It's saying we should probably discuss them in meta as they come up. That's probably what I should have done (and should maybe still happen if we want it reopened). I still think this falls squarely in the realm of the type of medical advice we have no business giving.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but I do not believe it is possible, at least not in a safe and healthy way!

The way that orthodontic braces work is by applying a force to your teeth, such that the teeth loosen slowly over time, and new bone growth forms around the new, slightly altered position, which is also a very slow process.

Answer (score 6):

There is no quick way of straighten a tooth and obviously not in a week. Don't attempt any teeth-straightening on your own as you can risk a pain or further complications without necessary knowledge. This require training and long-term practice. If this would be so simple, orthodontist wouldn't study that topic.

**If your tooth is slightly twisted, there is some reason for it**. Either you've another tooth either underneath (you can't know that without a proper X-Ray) or next to it or there is no really space for your tooth (and you need a palatal spreader to widen the upper jaw), or there is some potential complication and you can end up with [dental extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_extraction).

So make sure that you make an appointment with your your orthodonist before making a decision. There is no better person who can tell you the options than your orthodontist (always be open for a second opinion).

Today, one of the most popular options for realigning teeth (excempt traditional braces) is to use a clear retainer or brace appliance (such as Invisalign, Damon System, etc.). Or you can get a holding arch to prevent teeth from shifting.

If you're looking for any brace-less techniques, the only one is by gently massaging the teeth and gums every day in intended direction. However if you're not confident, please consult that with your orthodontist.

See also:

- [How to Straighten Your Teeth Without Braces](http://www.wikihow.com/Straighten-Your-Teeth-Without-Braces) at wikiHow